# Opting person out of mass mailings

Tags: massemailmessage

How do i make sure that a person is not included in further mass mailings?. I see an email optout button inside a contact, but when i run a list to send a mass email to, i cant track if they have opted out. Do they just not appear in the list.!

Thanks

Comment: Exactly, checking this checkbox makes that the contact no longer is selectable for mass emailing, which is what you are looking for it seems?

Comment: I am unsure if they are opted out or not. As I run a list i dont know if they are opted out. So they just dont appear in the list ryt..!

Comment: Hi Robin ,So you mean to say that they are opted out and so they do not appear in the list. Is that so.?

Comment: When creating your list of contacts to mass email to, Salesforce will already filter them out. This only applies to mass emailing, not 1-on-1 emails. See https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004203&language=en_US for more info.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your list of contacts to mass email to, Salesforce will already filter them out. This only applies to mass emailing, not 1-on-1 emails.

See [How do I use the Email opt-out field?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004203&language=en_US) for more info.